# How to Print username after user fills the "username" filed? why it disappears?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a JavaScript program the will do the following work:

- When the user fills the form/Gives the username, it should print the username.

The problem I am facing:

After clicking on submit button the result disappears. (note: the username is visible for about 0.1 seconds);

What I want

1. How can I stop it from disappearing?
2. Can I print the username before the user clicks in submit?

```
<form action="" name="jsform">
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input type="email" name="uemail" id="uemail" placeholder="Your Email">
    <input type="password" name="upass" id="main_pass" placeholder="Enter A Password">
    <input type="password" name="passconf" id="confirm_pass" placeholder="Confirm Password">
    <h3 id="printUserName"></h3>
</form>
```

```
function validateForm() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    document.getElementById('printUserName').innerHTML= userName + "is available" ;
    console.log(userName);

    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It disappears because the form is submitted to the same url essentially refreshing the page. You can prevent this binding a function to `onsubmit` event and calling `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` from within.
2. You can show the data before submit by binding a function to the `onchange` event.

Answer (score 0):

add submit handler to the form

```
<form action="" name="jsform" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

the form wont submit, if onsubmit returns false

Answer (score 0):

Attach your function to onSubmit event of your form and do your printing. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Don't forgot to add event.preventDefault() to the top of your function.
Refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp